# How to remove multiple files uploaded from an array based on user selection in javascript or angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

Hi I need to remove multiple files uploaded from an array based on user selection in javascript or angular.........
I have tried with below code

First we have some files that are uploaded in an array and are displayed in checkboxes as shown below in code

```
    <div *ngFor="let image of imagefilename" style="margin-left:10%">
              <label class="container" style="font-size:14px">
                {{image.name}}&nbsp;ModifiedDate:{{image.lastModifiedDate}}
                <input type="checkbox" style="float:left" value="{{image.name}}" [(ngModel)]="imageChecked" 
                       [name]="image.name">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span class="checkmark"></span> <br><br>
              </label>
                </div>
          <button *ngIf="imagefilename.length" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" (click)="resetimage(imagefilename)">Reset Selected files</button>
```

The user will click on the checkboxes that are to be removed and then click on the button displayed and

it calls a function as displayed below

```
 resetimage(imageName:any) {
for(var i = 0; i<this.imagefilename.length;i++){
if(this.imageChecked){
  this.imagefilename.splice(i,1);
      }
    }
  }
```

So in this function, only the first file in the array is removed although the user has selected multiple files to remove.

So please help me if there is any solution.

Expected result :
to remove multiple files uploaded from an array based on user selection in javascript or angular

Actual result :
Only first file is removed even though the user has selected multiple files.(as per my code)

Comment: Thanks Giannis ,is there any solution for the question??

Comment: The imageChecked should be specific to index because , The imageChecked Shoud be there for every image inside the (this.imagefilename) collection which can represents the selection of each image , instead of it you have a generic object called imageChecked , which will get updated to true or false if you select any image in the collection , and that's the reason the first image is getting deleted . if you select three images none would deleted , if you select 4 images the first image would be deleted . its because now your imageChecked object is behaving like a toggle switch .

Comment: Java script Should be :
resetimage(imageName:any) {
  for(var index = 0; index<this.imagefilename.length;index++){
    if(this.imagefilename.imageChecked){
      this.imagefilename.splice(index,1);
    }
  }
}

Comment: UI Code Should be :
<div *ngFor="let image of imagefilename" style="margin-left:10%">
    <label class="container" style="font-size:14px">
        {{image.name}}&nbsp;ModifiedDate:{{image.lastModifiedDate}}
        <input type="checkbox" style="float:left" value="{{image.name}}" [(ngModel)]="image.imageChecked" [name]="image.name">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
        <br>
        <br>
    </label>
</div>
<button *ngIf="imagefilename.length" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" (click)="resetimage(imagefilename)">Reset Selected files</button>

Comment: Hi redhatvicky,
i Have tried your answer but it is throwing error as -- 
Cannot read property 'Checked' of undefined
Please help if you have any solution for this

Comment: That's beacuse you will not have the object by default in the  "imagefilename", You have to introduce an object called "imageChecked" in the same place where you have introduced "lastModifiedDate" , So that the value comes from the model / controller . Now when you click the check box for selection the flag gets enabled and You can achieve what you require.

Comment: Hi redhatvicky , if you help me how to introduce that object .it will solve my problem so please help

Comment: Sure , But i would require few information. 1. The Image collection object is populated from Model/Controller. The Iamge objects comes from the database ? or you have hard coded the values in the model / controller. 2. Have you defined the definitions of the image inside the controller ? i.e the image properties like image name , image modified etc.

Comment: Hi redhatvicky,
thanks a lot 
1.... It is model
2.....It comes from database
3.... No i am using file upload (<input type = file) ans storing those files in an array called imageFIleName which is displayed 
so automatically i will get name and modified asa the user uploads a file

Comment: Cool , Then it seems to be simpler now . After retrieving from the database , you will have the image colletion object,  in our case its "imagefilename" which you use it to iterate and set the objects in the label and the input type check box ,when you retrieve it from the database you have to introduce the "imageChecked" object for each file object and add then to the imagefilename collection ( The new object introduced should be  Boolean object (imageChecked) ) and rest will work with the above snippet itself.

Comment: If you say in a code language it will be helpful to me as i could not get u
thanks for the quick response

Comment: I have think through a Simpler solution , You have a tag called name right , So you can just modify the js function like this , resetimage(imageName:any) {
  for(var index = 0; index<this.imagefilename.length;index++){
    if(document.getElementByName(this.imagefilename.name).checked){
      this.imagefilename.splice(index,1);
  }
}}

Comment: resetimage(imageName:any) { for(var index = 0; index<this.imagefilename.length;index++){ if(document.getElementByName(this.imagefilename[index].name).checked){ this.imagefilename.splice(index,1); } }}

Comment: I have made a small correction in the able code to retrieve the DOM element using the name and then find it whether its check or not , If its check we are removing it from the list , Let me know if it works or you face any problems.

Comment: Hi rehatvicky,
I have tried the same but the same error
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Checked' of undefined

Comment: console.log of this.imagefilename[index].name and this.imagefilename[index].value and this.imagefilename[index] , Moreover check whether the name of the checkbox generated using inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

your property `imageChecked` is not binded with image. You should add property `imageChecked` in `image` and modify html like below.

```
<div *ngFor="let image of imagefilename" style="margin-left:10%">
              <label class="container" style="font-size:14px">
                {{image.name}}&nbsp;ModifiedDate:{{image.lastModifiedDate}}
                <input type="checkbox" style="float:left" value="{{image.name}}" [(ngModel)]="image.imageChecked" 
                       [name]="image.name">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span class="checkmark"></span> <br><br>
              </label>
                </div>
          <button *ngIf="imagefilename.length" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" (click)="resetimage(imagefilename)">Reset Selected files</button>
```

And you code should be like this

```
resetimage(imageName:any) {
for(var i =this.imagefilename.length;i--){
if(this.imagefilename[i].imageChecked){
  this.imagefilename.splice(i,1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @lazydeveloper,
 i Have tried your answer but it is throwing error as -- Cannot read property 'Checked' of undefined Please help if you have any solution for this

Comment: Cannot read property 'Checked' of undefined => this is not related to my code..check your code thoroughly..

Comment: i think you have used Checked instead of imageChecked